# Grayline when Entry with Material Visual is focused in Xamarin Forms Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, material-design, material-components-android

I have used entry with visual as material in Xamarin Forms and I have faced the issue that the vertical line is appearing when the entry is tapped to make focus.

Note: Grayline appears for a few seconds and then disappears.

Screenshot:

[image: Gratline reference image which I have highlighted with yellow]

Comment: What's the version of XF in your project ? On Android, Material Visual requires a minimum version of 5.0 (API 21) or greater, and a TargetFramework of version 9.0 (API 28). In addition, your platform project requires Android support libraries 28.0.0 or greater, and its theme needs to inherit from a Material Components theme or continue to inherit from an AppCompat theme. For more information, see https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md.

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT

XF version I have used is 4.4.0.991864, target framework as you have mentioned and also support libraries of the latest one,

I have used this link to set up material design
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/visual/material-visual#initialize-material-visual


<Entry Visual="Material"  />

Comment: update the version to the latest version (4.8.x) .

Comment: Unfortunately not able to update the Xamarin forms versions.

Comment: I think the issue is caused by the version ..

Comment: I have checked with latest version and it has no issues but need to fix in this version.

Comment: @cruzier I believe your issue is the same with this one: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/9423 and per the github issue, it's fixed in v4.5.0, if you're not able to update to the latest version, you may try update to 4.5.0